# Mac screen stays lit on login prompt

Tags: mojave, power-management, screen-lock

My 2013 iMac running Mojave 10.14.3 has had this problem for a number of years and spans a few OS upgrades. When in locked mode, the screen can stay lit indefinitely, until I hit Esc.

Behavior is like this. I lock my Mac, or just walk away from it until it locks itself up. I touch my touchpad or press any key to light up the screen. The screen will the stay lit - for ever. I have to manually hit escape to put it back to sleep.

My settings:
I have screen saver on (10 minutes). 
In Power Savings, I have standard options. These are checked:
 Put hard disks to sleep
 Enable Power Naps

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Any antivirus installed? I've known BitDefender not let Macs drop properly to 'screen off'.

Comment: No. I don’t run any anti-viruses on this Mac. I do run BackBlaze backup service.

Comment: kk. I've never known Backblaze to hurt anything, have it on a couple of machines here, so that wouldn't be in my suspect list

Comment: I currently have a similar issue, where my iMac doesn't sleep when it's in the login screen (username & password), unless you manually click on "sleep".

Answer (score 1):

I was able to temporarily correct this problem by deleting:

```
/Users/xxx/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist
```

and restarting my computer.

This worked for a little bit, but stoped once I connected my iMac to my MBP as a Target Display.

Comment: Getting closer. Reset the System Management Controller (SMC), or in other words, shutting down and disconnecting from power, makes it go away until the next time I connect to Target Display.